# C# including other file

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

How can I access function in second.cs file?

> For example to call someFunction from second file in first_main.

*I tried this:*

**first_main.cs:**

```
using second;
namespace first_main
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow, funkcijos
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            someFuction();
        }
    }
}
```

**second.cs:**

```
namespace second
{
    public class funkcijos
    {
        public funkcijos()
        {

        }
        public void someFuction()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I use function in MainWindow class, from function class");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: function inside constructor?

Comment: You will have to pass a reference to `class MainWindow` to `class funkcijos` somehow. You could pass it to `someFunction()` as a parameter, for example. Or pass it to the `class funkcijos` constructor and save it in a class field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MetroWindow must be an interface, otherwise you can not inherit for both  MetroWindow, funkcijos. Multi-inheritance is not supported by .net

```
using second;
namespace first_main
{
   public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
        var second = new funkcijos();
        funkcijos.someFuction();
      }
    }
}

namespace second
{
   public class funkcijos
   {
      public funkcijos()
      {
      }

      public void someFuction()
      {
            MessageBox.Show("I use function in MainWindow class, from function class");
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your original question, it appears you are trying to implement a partial class across two different namespaces, or achieve multiple inheritance, neither of which is not possible in c#.

What you could do to achieve the same functionality is create an *extension method* which associates `someFuction` [sic] to the `MainWindow` class:

**first_main.cs:**

```
using second;

namespace first_main
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        MainWindow()
        {
            this.someFuction();
        }
    }
}
```

**second.cs:**

```
using first_main;

namespace second
{
    public static class MainWindowExtensions
    {
        public static void someFuction(this MainWindow instance)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, utilizing this approach, instances of `MainWindow` will appear to gain the methods stored in the extensions method class as if they were public instance members:

```
var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.someFuction();
```

Using the interface approach, you achieve no re-usability of code.  All you have is the *contract*, but you are still required to implement these methods everywhere the interface is used.  The advantage to solving your problem with this extension method approach is you achieve "*write once, use everywhere*".